# Sending required eth to a contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, nft

I'm currently developing a NFT with a sort of marketplace. The NFT info is based on a struct containing it's price. In the marketplace I'm trying to implement a buy function that fetches the price from the NFT contract and require that amount in the buy function. This is my current code.

```
function buyNFT(uint256 tokenId) external payable nonReentrant {
    ILandNFT ilandInterface = ILandNFT(NFTAddress);

    require(
        ilandInterface.stateOf(tokenId) == State.MAvailable,
        "This land NFT is not available!"
    );
    require(
        ilandInterface.priceOf(tokenId) >= msg.value,
        "The amount of CELO sent is not enough!"
    );

    require(
        msg.sender != ilandInterface.landOwnerOf(tokenId),
        "You can't buy your own land!"
    );

    // Receive the amount of CELO sent
    (bool sent, ) = owner().call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send CELO");

    // Update land status
    ilandInterface.updateLandState(tokenId, State.MUnavailable);

    // Set the initial lock to current timestamp
    lockStartTime[tokenId] = block.timestamp;

    /* Update the total land bought by the buyer 
        and add the new nft to its collection */
    increaseBoughtCount(msg.sender, tokenId);

    // Update the buyer
    ilandInterface.updateBuyer(tokenId, msg.sender);
}
```

The transaction calling the `buyNFT` function succeeds, but the amount of eth required is not being sent to the contract. Thanks in advance for any help!